# PHP array_fill array with multiples of the same record

Tags: php

I have this function; I'm trying to fill the `$records` array with multiple entries of each `$vendor`. Only the first record goes in the `$records` array 12 times like I want it to. Now I would like to get the rest to do the same.

```
function vendors()
{
    $vendor = [
        "Chick-Fil-A #03971 Houston TX" => 3,
        "Uber Trip Help.Uber.Com TX" => 8,
        "Starbucks Store 05 Houston TX" => 3,
        "Shell Service S Houston TX" => 3,
        "Ralphs #0 1200 N Centr Houston TX" => 3,
        "Nails Van Nuys TX" => 3,
        "Postmates Ed3F9 to Httpspostmate CA" => 3,
        "Pico Beauty Supply and SA Houston TX" => 3,
        "Big Mamas & Papas 818-679-9976 TX" => 3,
        "CIT-GO Houston TX" => 3,
        "Dollar Tree Houston TX" => 3,
        "McDonald's M6310 O Houston TX" => 5,
        "Jamba Juice - Houston TX" => 3,
        "Cvs/Pharm 10445--125 N Glendale" => 3,
    ];
    $records = array();
    foreach ($vendor as $key => $value)
    {
        $times = $value * 4;
        $records = array_fill(0, $times, $key);
    }
    return $records;
}
```

Comment: Please check this - https://3v4l.org/s6W5S . Do you want such output?

Comment: ....are you sure you want to use a new `$records` array on each loop?

Comment: Shawn Sonnier "If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Then return here and do the same with the tick/check-mark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!"

Answer (score 2):

you are over-writing your array variable again and again instead of assigning new data to it.

Do:

```
$records[] = array_fill(0, $times, $key);//assign data as child-array to your final array
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/rVdKg

Or may be you want like this:- https://3v4l.org/2Yb8B

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call array_fill it overwrites what you did in the previous call.

If you don't absolutely need to use array_fill you could replace the foreach with something like this:

```
foreach ($vendor as $key => $value){
        $times = $value * 4;
        for($x=0; $x<$times; $x++){
          if(!isset($records[$x])){
            $records[$x]=[];
        }
          array_push($records[$x], $key);
        }
}
```

Does that do what you are trying to do?